# AD (Azure Directory) group object not showing anything in react but it shows up in the console React/Spfx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, spfx, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to display my ad group, a single object, the first value in my ad group.
The code below seems to be working and I'm able to log the object `console.log(res);` and sure enough I do get the object and its properties logged in the console. The problem is that it does not show anything on my browser. It's just white and I don't see my `<h1>{() => {return groups.displayName}}</h1>` showing up anywhere.
Any help on this matter would be appreciated

Interface

```
export interface IUserItem {
    displayName: string,
    description?: string,
}
```

```
const EmployeeList = (props: IEmployeeListProps) => {

  const [groups, setGroups] = useState<IUserItem>();

  useEffect(() => {
    props.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient("3")
      .then((client: MSGraphClientV3) => {
        client
          .api("/groups/02c1fcf9-3708-4fad-a44d-1dc5de69abd9")
          .version("v1.0")
          .select("")
          .get((err: any, res: any) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error("MSGraphAPI Error")
              console.error(err);
              return;
            }
            console.log(res);
            setGroups(res.value);
          }).catch((e) => { console.log(e) });
      }).catch((e) => { console.log(e) })
  }, []);



  return (
    <div onLoad={() => console.log("Page has been loaded")} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <div>
          <h1>{() => {return groups.displayName}}</h1>  
        </div>      
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmployeeList
```

EDIT Screenshot of the console log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pw5da9lxtb4hok7/object%20log.png?dl=0

UPDATE/SOLUTION:
I was trying to set my groups object to the res.value instead of the res object.
The solution was just to change `setGroups(res.value);` to `setGroups(res);`

Comment: Can you please show some output that is coming to the console

Comment: Sure, the object log is quite long with a lot of attributes and unnecessary odata, so it's not really formatted on stack. I took a screenshot of the log though and dropped it in my dropbox. Here is the log https://www.dropbox.com/s/pw5da9lxtb4hok7/object%20log.png?dl=0

Comment: that's mean which are showing me object, you are setting this state like `setGroups(res.value);` because you consoling only `console.log(res);` res value, and you are setting the `res.value` in `setGroup`. Are you sure you are entering the exact data in the setGroup state?

Comment: Argh, yes. That's true because it's an object that I am setting in my setState I need to set it to the  ```  res ``` object and not the  ```  res.value ``` object property. I've changed the ```setGroups(res.value);``` to ```setGroups(res);```. That did the job, Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>{() => {return groups.displayName}}</h1>
```

should be

```
<h1>{groups?.displayName}</h1>
```

Comment: Hey Nikolay, I've tried that too but to no avail unfortunately. It still shows up in the console but not on the site itself

Answer (score -1):

I'm not pretty sure but seems like you try to render groups.displayName before it is defined.

try using it with optional chaining

```
<h1>{() => {return groups?.displayName}}</h1>
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and it's not changing the outcome. It's still showing a blank site and with the object being logged in the console. Also should the object not already be defined as I set the state inside the useEffect, which in practise is run after the first render?